# How to disable google auto ads in header section of wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, adsense

i want to disable the google ads in my header section of my website because it is destroying my website design. ads arre dispaying as shownnn in thhe imaage below. you can see them in this page [https://digitalmoney.space/forum/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) . i already tried disabling it from google adsense but i am unable to find the block to disable it. Can you help me with this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsdXe.png)

i tried using google adsense to remove the unwanted block but i didnt find the blocks to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Form checking your site I can see you're using Site Kit. While there are no configurations within Site Kit to limit ad placement, luckily, you can do so from the AdSense platform directly. What you're looking for is the ad preview tool. See below:
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/12626543?hl=en

You can also wish to disable anchor ads (which also appear at the top) from within your AdSense Auto ads settings.

Hopefully the above is of use.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem on my https://kaznews.kz/ website.
1st I tried to disable overlay formats in adsense setup and
that didn't help.
Then tried exclude some areas, that helped partially.
Finally, kept everything as it was, hope Google will fix it soon.

Or we can write some css for generated classes, here is the code, I put it on my sie, it works for now, but in case any issues please tell me:

```html
.google-auto-placed {
    height: 0px !important;
}

.adsbygoogle_adsbygoogle-noablate {
    margin: auto !important;
}
.adsbygoogle-noablate {
    margin: auto !important;
}
```